# Permutation Test on Graphs - igraph

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory, network-analysis

I am trying to compute a permutation test of the E-I index to evaluate the homophily of a network and to measure the signifance of the E-I index. However using the *permute()* function to create a new graph, by permuting vertex ids, the network will permute, but by executing the E-I index it gives me always the same result of 0.25. So is there anything wrong with the permutation function?

```
actors <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                            "Esmeralda", "Ben", "Fritz", "Jon", "Anna",
                            "Julia"),
                     age=c(48,33,45,34,21, 12,33,44,66,99),
                     gender=c("F","M","F","M","F", "F","M","F","M","F"))

relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David",
                               "David", "Esmeralda",  "Cecil", "David",
                               "Esmeralda", "Jon", "Anna",
                               "Julia", "Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David"),
                        to=c("Alice", "Bob", "David", "Esmeralda",  "Cecil", "David", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Fritz", "Jon", "Anna", "Alice", "Bob", "Cecil"),
                        same.dept=c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE, TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE, FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE),
                        friendship=c(4,5,5,2,1,1,1,3,5,7,9,1, 7,8,2,4), advice=c(4,5,5,4,2,3,1,5,7,8,2,4, 7,8,2,4))
g <- graph.data.frame(relations, directed=TRUE, vertices=actors)


V(g)$name <- as.character(vertex_attr(g, "gender"))
edges <- get.data.frame(g)

external <- length(which(edges$from != edges$to))

internal <- length(which(edges$from == edges$to))

ei_index = (external - internal) / nrow(edges)

new.graph <- permute(g, sample(vcount(g)))
```

Answer (score 3):

The igraph documentation says `permute keeps all graph, vertex and edge attributes of the graph.` This means you're just changing the order of the node list. Below is an example of how the Vertex lists are different, but the edge lists remain the same.

[image: permute]

Would a function like `rewire` work for you?

```
ei_index <- function(g){
  edges <- get.data.frame(g)

  external <- length(which(edges$from != edges$to))

  internal <- length(which(edges$from == edges$to))

  ei_index = (external - internal) / nrow(edges)
  ei_index
}

set.seed(4321)
sapply(1:20, function(x){
  temp_g <- rewire(g, each_edge(p = 1, loops = F))
  ei_index(temp_g)
})
```

[image: rewired]